# How to save my python script with widget to html page?

Tags: python, html, widget

With my first python script, I was able to export my script in html :

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv('xxxx/Test.txt')
df.head()

fig = px.line(df, x = 'Date', y ='Total Used', title='DF command graph')
fig.add_scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Free'])

fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.write_html("/xxx/xxx/xxx/file.html")
fig.show()
```

Now, I've this script in python :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

button = widgets.Button(description="graph")
display(button)

def graph():
    df = pd.read_csv('/xxx/xxx/xxx/Test.txt')
    df.head()
    fig = px.line(df, x = 'Date', y ='Total Used', title='DF command graph')
    fig.update_traces(mode='markers')
    fig.show();

output = widgets.Output()

@output.capture()
def on_button_clicked(b):
    graph();

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(output)
```

There is an easy way to save it in html while keeping the interaction with the button ?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Absolutely.
Some people used `nbconvert` but it's necessary to have jupyter notebook. I would like a soluce without used jupyter if it's possible, like in my first code.